# como pasar variable de nodejs(Expressjs) a javascript(lado del cliente)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo este fragmento de codigo en nodejs

```
app.get('/consul', function(req, res, next) { 
  // 
    res.render('c_pUser', { title: conUsers});
});
```

la variable title quiero pasarlo a javascript del lado del cliente

intente mostrarlo en javascript del lado del cliente asi:

```
var nuevaVariable=<%=title%>;
alert(nuevaVariable);
```

pero me da error

como puedo pasar la variable de nodejs a javascript del lado del cliente?

Answer (score 0):

la solución fue:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(title)}
h3=local_data//mostramos en el archivo .jade
```

Comment: Si .jade te refieres al módulo para crear vistas, te sugiero actualizarlo a pug, es exactamente lo mismo pero cambió de nombre. Quizá te esté saliendo una advertencia en la consola al ejecutar las vistas. Sólo lo instalas con npm y tus archivos en vez de .jade es .pug.

Comment: @J.Correa algo oficial donde encuentro?

Comment: @m3w aquí https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: Explica porque es la solución.